# Filtering / smoothing a step function to retrieve biggest increments

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas Series where the index are date time.

I can plot my function with the `step()` function which plots each point of the Series relatively to the time (x is the time).

I want a less precise approach of the evolution in time. So I need to reduce the number of steps, and ignore the smallests increments. 
[image]
The only way I found is to use the `poly1d()` function from numpy to interpolate the points as a polynomial, and then to step the function. Unfortunately I am loosing the time index during the transformation because the index of a polynomial are x.

Is there a way to ‘simplify’ my function to only get the dates (x values) of the biggest changes on the y axis instead of having all the dates for any change ? 
As I wrote above, I'd like to have only the biggest increments and not the small changes.

Here is the exact data:

```
2016-01-02    -5.418440
2016-01-09    -9.137942
2016-01-16    -9.137942
2016-01-23    -9.137942
2016-01-30    -9.137942
2016-02-06   -11.795107
2016-02-13   -11.795107
2016-02-20   -11.795107
2016-02-27   -11.795107
2016-03-05   -11.795107
2016-03-12   -13.106988
2016-03-19   -13.106988
2016-03-26   -13.106988
2016-04-02   -13.106988
2016-04-09   -13.106988
2016-04-16   -13.106988
2016-04-23   -13.106988
2016-04-30   -11.458878
2016-05-07     0.051123
2016-05-14     2.010179
2016-05-21    -3.210870
2016-05-28    -0.726291
2016-06-04     5.841818
2016-06-11     5.067061
2016-06-18     5.789375
2016-06-25    16.455159
2016-07-02    22.518294
2016-07-09    39.834977
2016-07-16    54.685965
2016-07-23    54.685965
2016-07-30    55.169290
2016-08-06    55.169290
2016-08-13    55.169290
2016-08-20    53.366569
2016-08-27    45.758675
2016-09-03    10.976592
2016-09-10    -0.554887
2016-09-17    -8.653451
2016-09-24   -18.198305
2016-10-01   -22.218711
2016-10-08   -21.158434
2016-10-15   -11.723798
2016-10-22    -9.928957
2016-10-29   -17.498315
2016-11-05   -22.850454
2016-11-12   -25.190656
2016-11-19   -27.250960
2016-11-26   -27.250960
2016-12-03   -27.250960
2016-12-10   -27.250960
```

Comment: You could run a diff on the series and then filter/mask by a threshold. That way you maintain the index

Comment: If you could share the data we could try to help you better...

Comment: @RiccardoPetraglia Thanks I've edited the question

Comment: @Will thanks for your answer, do you have an example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to create a mask from your original series where the absolute difference in value from the previous value in the series is compared against your sensitivity threshold. The mask is simply a boolean selection array (matrix) for filtering your original series.

```
#my_series is your Series
threshold = 10.0
diff_series = my_series.diff.abs()
mask = diff_series > threshold
#now plot the masked values only or create new series from it etc.
my_series[mask].plot()
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.  Code-only answers are discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

so this is my idea:

```
# Load the data
a = load_table('<your_data_file>', delim_whitespace=True, names=['value'], index_col=0)

# Create and additional column containing the difference 
#+between two consecutive values:
a['diff'] = a.value.diff()

# select only the value of the 'diff' column higher than a certain threshold
#+and copy them to a new frame:
b = a[abs(a['diff']) > .5] # The threshold (.5) could be what you think is the best

# Plot your new graph
b.value.plot()
```

Hope this is helpful...

Answer (score -1):

You could use [pandas resample function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html).

Import the data and set the columns to 'Date' and 'Values'. The rest parses the Date column as datetime.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df.columns = ['Date','Values']
df.Date = df.Date.map(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x,'%Y-%m-%d'))
df.set_index('Date',inplace=True)
```

You can now resample the timeseries. E.g by month:

```
resampled_df = df.resample('M').mean()
resampled_df.head()
```

And finally, to plot it.

```
resampled_df.plot()
```

Comment: not really answering the question. OP is not asking for average values across regular time intervals